# Applying multiple conditions to a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some output from an online task that I need to wrangle into a usable form for scoring, which requires multiple conditions in order to be wrangled correctly. I tried using if and else statements but I am having a hard time meeting all the conditions needed this way.
A description of the data and conditions needed - in the first column there are three possible values corresponding to the person's response: either 'yes', 'no', or 'NR' (meaning no response given yet). In the second column is a type of counter, which is supposed to run from 1-5 sequentially, but it will repeat a value if the person held down the key for too long. So for each count in the second column, I want there to be one corresponding response in the first column, which should be the first response given ('yes' or 'no') for that count. If no response is given during that entire count, it should stay as 'NR'. The count then repeats itself from 1-5 again. For example, this input data:

```
   response  count
0       yes      1
1       yes      1
2       yes      1
3        no      1
4       yes      1
5        no      2
6        no      2
7        no      2
8        NR      3
9        NR      3
10       no      3
11       NR      3
12       NR      4
13       NR      4
14       NR      4
15      yes      5
16      yes      5
17       NR      1
18       NR      1
19       NR      2
20      yes      3
21      yes      3
22      yes      3
23       no      4
24      yes      4
25       no      5
```

Should reduce to this:

```
  response  count
0      yes      1
1       no      2
2       no      3
3       NR      4
4      yes      5
5       NR      1
6       NR      2
7      yes      3
8       no      4
9       no      5
```

It is a bit of a confusing problem, and so far I haven't found a combination of conditions or if/else statements applied to arrays that have given me the outcome I wanted. Any help or ideas would be much appreciated!

Source code for input data:

```
response = ['yes','yes','yes','no','yes','no','no','no','NR','NR','no','NR','NR','NR','NR','yes','yes','NR','NR','NR','yes','yes','yes','no','yes','no']
count = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]
data_dict = {'response': response,
            'count':count}
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO... Can you please provide your source code so far (as text, NOT as image). It is much easier to improve your code than start from scratch. Help us to help you...

Comment: Thank you! I have added the source code I used to produce the input data in an edit above. Mind you this is just an example I have created to exemplify all the possible exceptions/heterogeneity that can occur in the input data which the conditions need to take care of to produce the desired output. I am not sure if a dataframe is the best way to go about this, but I was trying with arrays before and found myself far too deep in nested loops...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['count', (df['count'] != df['count'].shift()).cumsum()])['response']\
  .apply(lambda x: 'NR' if (x.nunique()==1) & (x == 'NR').all() else x.loc[x!='NR'].iloc[0])\
  .sort_index(level=1).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
count
1    yes
2     no
3     no
4     NR
5    yes
1     NR
2     NR
3    yes
4     no
5     no
Name: response, dtype: object
```

Details:

Let's generate a series to get the repeating groups first:

```
(df['count'] != df['count'].shift()).cumsum()
```

Using this series, along with 'count' we can create groups of responses,

If the count of unique responses is equal 1 and if that response is 'NR', then return 'NR' for that group.  Else, return the first repsonse that isn't 'NR' using `x.loc[X!='NR'].iloc[0]`.

Comment: Brilliant! I tried this on my actual data and it works perfectly. If it is not too much trouble, could you explain the logic of what you have done? This is the first time I have seen a lambda function used in practice.

Comment: Yes... sure give me a few minutes, I will explain.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you very much for your explanation.